# Could not sort by clicking Column name

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I m using my sql phpmyadmin
I m not able to sort (order by) while clicking fields name at the top of table. 
[image]

In the above image if i click Id means(highlighted) its not showing sorted table instead of that it showing insert menu as follows.

[image]

Why this is happening ? how can i solve this?

Comment: There is no requirement of single row sorting thats why phpmyadmin dont give the option for single record set, try one more row in the table then sort it, that will work.

Comment: sorry,  for reference only  i gave single record screenshot.  I have more than 100 record actually.

Comment: phpmyadmin isn't great but I could image you could run a SELECT query with ORDER BY in the SQL tab and basically get the same thing

Comment: Ya. Thats what i m doing now. but i just want to know why this is happening for some selected tables not for all.

Comment: @Joyner I find phpmyadmin to cause more issues and be a pain in general than anything else, and it's super slow. I primarily use Sequel Pro but if you use Windows I'd go with MySql Workbench.

Comment: @Nick. Thank you . I ll try your suggestion :)

Comment: Let me make sure I understand you correctly: when you click on the column header for 'id', it takes you directly to the Insert page? That's quite unusual. Which phpMyAdmin version are you using and which browser? Can you try with a different browser? Do you have any browser extensions or add-ons installed?

Comment: @IsaacBennetch I m using xamp server. Php MyAdmin version : 4.7.7.
I tried out with Chrome and Edge browsers, Both directing to Insert Page.
But its not like Normal Insertion Page. 
Normally in insertion page we will have all fields that we have in table but in my case its showing differently as i shown above.

Answer (score 0):

when click on any  column you should be shift + click
[image: like as notes in image]